# Facebook like button doesn't work in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I have followed some tutorials how to use facebook with android app. I managed to implement working "log in" button and "share" button however I cant make like button work properly. After I press it i get this question image appearing for a second and then it disapears:

[image]

Here is my application code(its simple activity with fragment in it):

```
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private TextView simpleTextView;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //PODSTAWOWE RZECZY
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); //facebook
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        registerCallback();

        //JAKIEŚ TOKENY I INNE TRACKERY DO UPDATÓW
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "currentAccessTokenChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                simpleTextView.setText("current access token changed");
            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                // App code
                if (currentProfile != null) {
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Welcome " + currentProfile.getName());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Profil null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        //ZACZYNAMY ŚLEDZIĆ
        profileTracker.startTracking();
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);

        //SPRAWDZAMY CZY ZALOGOWANY JEST UZYTKOWNIK I ROBIMY SET-UP PROGRAMU
        simpleTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        checkIfLogged();
        setFacebookLoginButton();
        setFacebookLikeButton();
        setFacebookShareButton();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //STOPUJEMY TRACKING
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    //========================= CUSTOM METHODS ========================================
    private void checkIfLogged(){
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            simpleTextView.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void setFacebookLoginButton(){
        LoginButton facebookButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        facebookButton.setFragment(this);
    }
    private void registerCallback(){
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "too bad you didn't log in...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "that's that error shit...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    private void setFacebookLikeButton(){
        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
        likeView.setFragment(this);
        likeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "masz chuja nie lajka...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        likeView.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
    }
    private void setFacebookShareButton(){
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://joemonster.org"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://joemonster.org/i/2015/05/pasazer.jpg")).
                setContentDescription("Prawdopodobnie najlepsza strona we wszechświecie!")
                .setContentTitle("Joe Monster")
                .build();

        ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setFragment(this);
        shareButton.setShareContent(content);
    }
}
```

Other concerning behaviour:

- If I use "share" button to log in then my "log in" button doesn't change to  display "Log out". If I then click "log in" button and cancel it. I will have to "log in" again with "share" or "like" button.
- If I use "log in" button to log in then below like button I see number of likes this site get.

I don't have facebook app installed in my virtual device.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Are you using your own profile, or some other FB profile?

Comment: Also, the "share" behavior is totally expected. If the user hasn't authorized your app with any permissions, then they're only logging in to share, and are not logging in to grant your app permissions, so you wouldn't see the Log Out text on the LoginButton.

Comment: Android version 4.1 and I also tried it on real device. I'am using some test facebook account. I was not aware of that "share" behaviour! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the Like button requires app approval, so during development, only users with Admin/Developer/Tester roles in your app can access it. Once it's approved, then any user can use the feature.

Comment: How can I make my app approved? do I need it even if Im just trying to "like" some page via facebook account? How to add/change Admin/Developer/Tester grants?  Im only asking for some further directions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Okey I just found answer to this one question. I can add Developer/Admin/Tester accounts in "Roles" section in _https://developers.facebook.com/apps/...._

Comment: Yup, while you're developing your app, you can add people to those roles, and have them test out the app. But before you publish to the play store, you need FB to approve your app to use the native like button.